# To select a row in a table that posts back

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver in java and got stuck at a place.Actually there is a table on page in which on selecting each row the page posts back and take user to next page.In HTML javascript is being used.The html of page looks like this:-

```
<td onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$WorklistCtrl$WorklistView','Select$4')" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">
  kalis, jack
</td>
```

This is a cell value in the table and when we takes mouse over this value it acts as a lick as javascript is being used in it but I am not able to click on this using selenium.

Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `kalis, jack ` is all that is to the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below line for clicking the element.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'kalis, jack')]")).click();
```